# 'connection unexpectedly closed' while using rsync with various command line arguments

Tags: ssh, rsync

I want to copy an iso file from the server to my computer using `rsync`. I used the following command but something is wrong and I can't figure out what. I've checked the location of the key file and original file.

```
rsync --progress -avz -e 'ssh -v -i ./.ssh/new_keys node@<ip_address>' node@<ip_address>:~/ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso ./Downloads/Ubuntu_Server.iso
```

This is the log created by `-v` parameter.

```
OpenSSH_7.3p1 Debian-1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <ip_address> [<ip_address>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ./.ssh/new_keys type 3
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file ./.ssh/new_keys-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3p1 Debian-1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <ip_address>:22 as 'node'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:jXVkrQn/jcw9yrL/mQEvT0v2aXxRd9WZo7BjiO6i1eU
debug1: Host '<ip_address>' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/papagolf/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: ./.ssh/new_keys
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 blen 172
Enter passphrase for key './.ssh/new_keys': 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <ip_address> ([<ip_address>]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending command: <ip_address> rsync --server --sender -vlogDtprze.iLsfx . ~/ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
bash: <ip_address>: command not found
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2580, received 2776 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4231.2, received 4552.7
debug1: Exit status 127
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
```

Comment: Afaik you do not need to use ssh since rsync is already ssh.

Comment: @aurelien : But it worked when I tried the same syntax to send a file from my PC to the server.

Comment: Try that: rsync -aHSv --progress ~/from aurelien@server:/to

Comment: And: Try that: rsync -aHSv --progress aurelien@server:/from ~/to

Comment: Or you can also just use scp command since you just wish a simple file.

Comment: I think you only need `rsync --progress -avz -e 'ssh -v -i ./.ssh/new_keys' node@<ip_address>:~/ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso ./Downloads/Ubuntu_Server.iso`. So remove the `node@<ip_address>` form `-e ssh '-v -i ...'`

Comment: @Thomas : Yup! That worked. Could you please write it as an answer.

Comment: Is there a firewall coming in between your server and personal computer?

Comment: @GC13 : Nope! There isn't any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a command as follows.

```
rsync --progress -avz -e 'ssh -v -i ./.ssh/new_keys' node@<ip_address>:~/ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso ./Downloads/Ubuntu_Server.iso
```

So remove the `node@<ip_address>` form `-e ssh '-v -i ...'`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error message:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.3]
```

The problem: `rsync` was not installed on the target system.

After installing `rsync` on the target system everything ran without error.

Comment: install rsync in `ubuntu/debian` with `apt install rsync`

Answer (score 0):

in my case such command

```
rsync -vaP -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_test" ~/source/grafana-test-logs sradmin@10.1.1.1:/mnt/test/logs
```

works after `/mnt/test/logs` has a proper permission, so I needed `chmod`/`chown` on remote server

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem (well same error message id not the same problem),

It went away when I removed the `--compress` argument.   in this instance that would be the `-z` in `-avz`.

Comment: I've seen this scenario too, but in my experience there is a message about a missing library. Did you not get that?